# Search for if column has 'a' AND 'b'

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Suppose you have two tables... table 1 and table 2.

table 1 columns are name / age / area

table 2 has area / job title

I would like to select area and job title only if the area includes both names 'sarah' and 'Phillip' (has to include BOTH the given names)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is a combination of `exists`, `group by` `having` and `count`:

```
SELECT area, JobTitle
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT t1.Area
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE t1.Area = t2.Area
    AND Name IN('sarah', 'Phillip')
    GROUP BY t1.Area
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.Name) = 2
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method is not quite as flexible as the aggregation method.  However, you have two tables, and it might have better performance:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.area = t2.area and t1.name = 'sarah') and
      exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.area = t2.area and t1.name = 'Phillip');
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `table1(area, name)`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a unique constraint on table1 for (area, name) and if you have performance problems when using the more general answers, you could experiment with joins - which the DB engine can sometimes optimize more than a correlated subquery:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
join table1 t1a on t1a.area = t2.area and t1a.name = 'sarah'
join table1 t1b on t1b.area = t2.area and t1b.name = 'Phillip';
```